# After implementing pagination, im having UIImage issues on scrolling tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Currently have a tableview that contains different images in each cell, and im downloading the image from a URL im obtaining from JSON and putting that as the imageviews image.  My issue is, after i do my pagination call, the images that i just scrolled past become a single image and stick and only the newly paginated information is displaying the correct information.

The way the data is given in JSON most of the data is contained in an array of objects that contain most of the information except images.  Images are given separately in a dictionary that takes the objects id and matches it and then provides the image URL for the appropriate object.  I implemented pagination in my Networking class where im doing the JSON download call:

```
func downloadGamesByPlatformIDJSON(platformID: Int?, fields: String?, include: String?, pageURL: String?, completed: @escaping () -> () ) {
        var urlString : String?
        
        if pageURL == nil {
            urlString = "https://api.thegamesdb.net/v1/Games/ByPlatformID?apikey=\(apiKey)&id=\(platformID!)"
            
            if fields != nil {
                urlString = urlString! + "&fields=" + fields!
            }
            if include != nil {
                
                urlString = urlString! + "&include=" + include!
            }
            
        } else {
            urlString = pageURL!
        }
        print(urlString!)
        let url = URL(string: "\(urlString!)")!
        print(url)
        var requestHeader = URLRequest.init(url: url)
        requestHeader.httpMethod = "GET"
        requestHeader.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: requestHeader) { (data, response, error) in
            
            if error != nil {
                print("error = \(error)")
                completed()
            }
            
            if error == nil {
                do {
                    print("error = nil")
                    let json = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)
                    
                    print(json)
                    
                    if let jsonDecodedPlatforms = try JSONDecoder().decode(ByPlatformIDData?.self, from: data!) {
                        
                        print(jsonDecodedPlatforms)
                        let decodedJSON = jsonDecodedPlatforms.data?.games
                        self.boxart = jsonDecodedPlatforms.include.boxart
                        self.baseURL = jsonDecodedPlatforms.include.boxart.baseURL
                        self.page = jsonDecodedPlatforms.pages
                        
                        if let parseJSON = decodedJSON {
                     
                          var items = self.games
                            var boxarts = self.imageArray
                            items.append(contentsOf: parseJSON)
                            
                            if self.initialOffset < items.count {
                                self.games = items
                                self.imageArray = boxarts
                                self.initialOffset = items.count
                                
                            } else {
                                self.games = items
                                self.imageArray = boxarts
                            }
                            
                            
                        }
                        
                        
                    }
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        
                        completed()
                        print(data)
                    }
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
                
            }
            
        }.resume()
        
    }
    
    
}
```

So what im doing is if im on the last cell, i download the next page of data and append it to the array of objects.  This seems to work fairly well, but the images are just singely downloaded to the cell, they arent in an array of separate objects.  Ive made several attempts to take the downloaded image, append it to an image array, apply the image at the indexPath.row to the imageview and then treat it the same way im treating the rest of the information.  This results in a crash as it cannot find any index beyond the first.  Im pulling my hair out.  What did i miss?  Any help is appreciated.

Here is my other associated code:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ViewControllerTableViewCell

 if indexPath.row == (network.games.count - 1) && network.page?.next != nil {
            pageURL = network.page?.next
            
            network.downloadGamesByPlatformIDJSON(platformID: nil, fields: nil, include: nil, pageURL: network.page?.next) {
                print("pagination successful")
                tableView.reloadData()
                
            }
        }

  if frontImageName != nil {

            cell.tableViewCoverImage.loadImage(from: imageUrl) { print("tableViewCoverImage loaded!")
                self.network.imageArray.append(cell.tableViewCoverImage.image)
                self.coverImage = cell.tableViewCoverImage.image!
                cell.tableViewCoverImage.image = self.network.imageArray[indexPath.row]
                
               
            }
        }
        else {
            cell.tableViewCoverImage.image = UIImage(named: "noArtNES")

        }
  
        
        return cell
}
```

```
extension UIImageView {
    func loadImage(from url: String, completed: @escaping () -> ()) {
        
        
        
        let imageURL = URL(string: url)
        
        DispatchQueue.global().async { [weak self] in
            
            if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: imageURL!) {
                
                if let image = UIImage(data: data) {
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self?.image = image
                        completed()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

```
{
    "code": 200,
    "status": "Success",
    "data": {
        "count": 20,
        "games": [
            {
                "id": 4,
                "game_title": "Star Fox 64",
                "release_date": "1997-06-30",
                "platform": 3,
                "players": 4,
                "overview": "The Lylat system has been invaded!  Join Fox McCloud and his Star Fox team as they fight to save the galaxy from the clutches of the evil Andross.  Travel to many different 3-D worlds.  Battle the enemy in the air and on the ground and listen in as Fox McCloud interacts with a cast of characters.\r\n\r\nSee how it feels to feel what you see!  The N64 Rumble Pak controller accessory instantly transmits all the bumps and blasts during the action.  It’s a new jolt to your game play experience!\r\n\r\n* Four Players compete simultaneously in Vs. mode!\r\n* Game Pak memory saves the top 10 scores!\r\n* Outstanding cinema scenes tell the Star Fox saga!",
                "last_updated": "2018-08-11 15:01:11",
                "rating": "E - Everyone",
                "coop": "No",
                "youtube": "jsEcmfPwnHo",
                "os": null,
                "processor": null,
                "ram": null,
                "hdd": null,
                "video": null,
                "sound": null,
                "developers": [
                    6037
                ],
                "genres": [
                    1,
                    8
                ],
                "publishers": [
                    3
                ],
                "alternates": [
                    "Lylat Wars"
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 42,
                "game_title": "Mario Party",
                "release_date": "1999-02-08",
                "platform": 3,
                "players": 4,
                "overview": "Every game in the main series has a standard Party Mode in which up to four players play through a board, trying to collect as many stars as possible. In every turn, each player rolls a die and progresses on the board, which usually has branching paths. Coins are primarily earned by performing well in a minigame played at the end of each turn. On most boards, players earn stars by reaching a star space and purchasing a star for a certain amount of coins. The star space appears randomly on one of several pre-determined locations and moves every time a star is purchased, usually occupying a blue space.\r\nEvery Mario Party contains at least 50 to almost 110 minigames with a few different types. Four-player games are a free-for-all in which players compete individually. In 2-on-2 and 1-on-3 minigames, players compete as two groups, cooperating to win, even though they are still competing individually in the main game. Some minigames in Mario Party are 4-player co-op, even though it doesn't say it. In most situations, winners earn ten coins each.",
                "last_updated": "2018-07-11 21:05:01",
                "rating": "E - Everyone",
                "coop": "No",
                "youtube": "sScj7MwjHBs",
                "os": null,
                "processor": null,
                "ram": null,
                "hdd": null,
                "video": null,
                "sound": null,
                "developers": [
                    3923
                ],
                "genres": [
                    1,
                    2,
                    6,
                    11
                ],
                "publishers": [
                    3
                ],
                "alternates": null
            },
            {
                "id": 68,
                "game_title": "Turok: Dinosaur Hunter",
                "release_date": "1997-03-04",
                "platform": 3,
                "players": 1,
                "overview": "Much like your usual 1st person shooter, although with dinosaurs as your main enemy. Includes 14 high tech weapons, like the Quad Rocket Launcher and the Atomic Fusion Cannon. You control Turok, who must take on the Campaigner and his highly evolved dino's. The objective is to collect pieces of the Chronoscepter, which is the only weapon that can help to destory the Campaigner, and to stop him from using the power of the weapon to destory the Lost Land.",
                "last_updated": "2020-04-16 11:18:30",
                "rating": "M - Mature 17+",
                "coop": "No",
                "youtube": "3AKbul3ILM0",
                "os": null,
                "processor": null,
                "ram": null,
                "hdd": null,
                "video": null,
                "sound": null,
                "developers": [
                    4065
                ],
                "genres": [
                    8
                ],
                "publishers": [
                    28
                ],
                "alternates": null
            },
            
            {
                "id": 216,
                "game_title": "Super Mario 64",
                "release_date": "1996-09-29",
                "platform": 3,
                "players": 1,
                "overview": "Mario is super in a whole new way! Combining the finest 3-D graphics ever developed for a video game and an explosive sound track, Super Mario 64 becomes a new standard for video games. It's packed with bruising battles, daunting obstacle courses and underwater adventures. Retrieve the Power Stars from their hidden locations and confront your arch nemesis - Bowser, King of the Koopas!",
                "last_updated": "2020-07-09 20:19:39",
                "rating": "E - Everyone",
                "coop": "No",
                "youtube": "cx78guiPMP8",
                "os": null,
                "processor": null,
                "ram": null,
                "hdd": null,
                "video": null,
                "sound": null,
                "developers": [
                    6043
                ],
                "genres": [
                    1,
                    2,
                    15
                ],
                "publishers": [
                    3
                ],
                "alternates": null
            },
         
            
            {
                "id": 239,
                "game_title": "A Bug's Life",
                "release_date": "1998-11-06",
                "platform": 3,
                "players": 1,
                "overview": "As hopeful hero Flik, you're the colony's last chance against the seed-grubbing grasshoppers. Run, fly, kick, squish, and slide through 15 challenging levels of 3-D animated gameplay. Outmaneuver 13 types of enemies, including The Bird and her deadly beak. Then, throw your weight around with tough antics like the Berry Attack and the Butt-Bounce. Because on this ride, you'll need more than just high hopes.\r\n\r\n• Search for power-ups, tokens and objects to use in the \"Living World.\"\r\n• Get a bug's-eye-view of a magical 3-D world.\r\n• Swing, fly, slide and navigate Flik through immense bug-infested levels.",
                "last_updated": "2018-08-11 15:01:11",
                "rating": "E - Everyone",
                "coop": "No",
                "youtube": "j0ITQ9h2o4c",
                "os": null,
                "processor": null,
                "ram": null,
                "hdd": null,
                "video": null,
                "sound": null,
                "developers": [
                    2383
                ],
                "genres": [
                    2
                ],
                "publishers": [
                    33
                ],
                "alternates": null
            },
            {
                "id": 240,
                "game_title": "Army Men: Sarge's Heroes",
                "release_date": "2000-11-16",
                "platform": 3,
                "players": 4,
                "overview": "CONFIDENTIAL. 0600 hours: Tan forces captured Bravo Company Commandos. General Plastro has new weapons of mass destruction: magnifying glass, M-80 firecrackers and the garbage disposal. This is a job for Sarge. Requisition M-60s, shotguns, bazookas, flame throwers, grenades, sniper rifles, mortars, mine sweepers and plenty of ammo. Good luck, soldier.",
                "last_updated": "2020-02-17 06:17:04",
                "rating": "T - Teen",
                "coop": "No",
                "youtube": "V5IbVO1MUbc",
                "os": null,
                "processor": null,
                "ram": null,
                "hdd": null,
                "video": null,
                "sound": null,
                "developers": [
                    77
                ],
                "genres": [
                    1,
                    8
                ],
                "publishers": [
                    63
                ],
                "alternates": null
            }
        ]
    },
    "include": {
        "boxart": {
            "base_url": {
                "original": "https://cdn.thegamesdb.net/images/original/",
                "small": "https://cdn.thegamesdb.net/images/small/",
                "thumb": "https://cdn.thegamesdb.net/images/thumb/",
                "cropped_center_thumb": "https://cdn.thegamesdb.net/images/cropped_center_thumb/",
                "medium": "https://cdn.thegamesdb.net/images/medium/",
                "large": "https://cdn.thegamesdb.net/images/large/"
            },
            "data": {
                "4": [
                    {
                        "id": 846,
                        "type": "boxart",
                        "side": "front",
                        "filename": "boxart/front/4-1.jpg",
                        "resolution": "1000x705"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 847,
                        "type": "boxart",
                        "side": "back",
                        "filename": "boxart/back/4-1.jpg",
                        "resolution": "1000x705"
                    }
                ],
                "42": [
                    {
                        "id": 581,
                        "type": "boxart",
                        "side": "back",
                        "filename": "boxart/back/42-1.jpg",
                        "resolution": "1000x693"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 215518,
                        "type": "boxart",
                        "side": "front",
                        "filename": "boxart/front/42-1.jpg",
                        "resolution": null
                    }
                ],
                "68": [
                    {
                        "id": 864,
                        "type": "boxart",
                        "side": "front",
                        "filename": "boxart/front/68-1.jpg",
                        "resolution": "1000x691"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 865,
                        "type": "boxart",
                        "side": "back",
                        "filename": "boxart/back/68-1.jpg",
                        "resolution": "1000x694"
                    }
                ],
                "141": [
                    {
                        "id": 7164,
                        "type": "boxart",
                        "side": "front",
                        "filename": "boxart/front/141-1.jpg",
                        "resolution": "2100x1532"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 7165,
                        "type": "boxart",
                        "side": "back",
                        "filename": "boxart/back/141-1.jpg",
                        "resolution": "2100x1532"
                    }
                ],
                "160": [
                    {
                        "id": 28559,
                        "type": "boxart",
                        "side": "front",
                        "filename": "boxart/front/160-1.jpg",
                        "resolution": "1000x688"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 28560,
                        "type": "boxart",
                        "side": "back",
                        "filename": "boxart/back/160-1.jpg",
                        "resolution": "1000x694"
                    }
                ],
                "161": [
                    {
                        "id": 894,
                        "type": "boxart",
                        "side": "back",
                        "filename": "boxart/back/161-1.jpg",
                        "resolution": "1000x697"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 83199,
                        "type": "boxart",
                        "side": "front",
                        "filename": "boxart/front/161-1.jpg",
                        "resolution": "1050x768"
                    }
                ],
                "162": [
                    {
                        "id": 517,
                        "type": "boxart",
                        "side": "back",
                        "filename": "boxart/back/162-1.jpg",
                        "resolution": "1000x686"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 111271,
                        "type": "boxart",
                        "side": "front",
                        "filename": "boxart/front/162-1.jpg",
                        "resolution": "2100x1536"
                    }
                ],
                "173": [
                    {
                        "id": 7353,
                        "type": "boxart",
                        "side": "front",
                        "filename": "boxart/front/173-1.jpg",
                        "resolution": "2100x1532"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 7354,
                        "type": "boxart",
                        "side": "back",
                        "filename": "boxart/back/173-1.jpg",
                        "resolution": "2100x1532"
                    }
                ],
                "175": [
                    {
                        "id": 7469,
                        "type": "boxart",
                        "side": "front",
                        "filename": "boxart/front/175-1.jpg",
                        "resolution": "2100x1532"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 7470,
                        "type": "boxart",
                        "side": "back",
                        "filename": "boxart/back/175-1.jpg",
                        "resolution": "2100x1532"
                    }
                ],
                "176": [
                    {
                        "id": 2445,
                        "type": "boxart",
                        "side": "front",
                        "filename": "boxart/front/176-1.jpg",
                        "resolution": "2100x1539"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2446,
                        "type": "boxart",
                        "side": "back",
                        "filename": "boxart/back/176-1.jpg",
                        "resolution": "2100x1533"
                    }
                ],
                "178": [
                    {
                        "id": 540,
                        "type": "boxart",
                        "side": "front",
                        "filename": "boxart/front/178-1.jpg",
                        "resolution": "1000x690"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 541,
                        "type": "boxart",
                        "side": "back",
                        "filename": "boxart/back/178-1.jpg",
                        "resolution": "2107x1473"
                    }
                ],
                "216": [
                    {
                        "id": 234524,
                        "type": "boxart",
                        "side": "back",
                        "filename": "boxart/back/216-1.jpg",
                        "resolution": null
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 235403,
                        "type": "boxart",
                        "side": "front",
                        "filename": "boxart/front/216-1.jpg",
                        "resolution": null
                    }
                ],
                "228": [
                    {
                        "id": 2429,
                        "type": "boxart",
                        "side": "front",
                        "filename": "boxart/front/228-1.jpg",
                        "resolution": "2100x1540"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2430,
                        "type": "boxart",
                        "side": "back",
                        "filename": "boxart/back/228-1.jpg",
                        "resolution": "2100x1536"
                    }
                ],
                "229": [
                    {
                        "id": 2431,
                        "type": "boxart",
                        "side": "front",
                        "filename": "boxart/front/229-1.jpg",
                        "resolution": "2100x1524"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2432,
                        "type": "boxart",
                        "side": "back",
                        "filename": "boxart/back/229-1.jpg",
                        "resolution": "2100x1540"
                    }
                ],
                "230": [
                    {
                        "id": 538,
                        "type": "boxart",
                        "side": "front",
                        "filename": "boxart/front/230-1.jpg",
                        "resolution": "1000x682"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 539,
                        "type": "boxart",
                        "side": "back",
                        "filename": "boxart/back/230-1.jpg",
                        "resolution": "1000x687"
                    }
                ]
               
            }
        },
        "platform": {
            "data": {
                "3": {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "Nintendo 64",
                    "alias": "nintendo-64"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "pages": {
        "previous": null,
        "current": "https://api.thegamesdb.net/v1/Games/ByPlatformID?apikey=8b574d53e9ff612a214486cfe8def1f5c045b0e4eaac50cfd54aa7873d89fd7b&id=3&fields=players%2Cpublishers%2Cgenres%2Coverview%2Clast_updated%2Crating%2Cplatform%2Ccoop%2Cyoutube%2Cos%2Cprocessor%2Cram%2Chdd%2Cvideo%2Csound%2Calternates&include=boxart%2Cplatform&page=1",
        "next": "https://api.thegamesdb.net/v1/Games/ByPlatformID?apikey=8b574d53e9ff612a214486cfe8def1f5c045b0e4eaac50cfd54aa7873d89fd7b&id=3&fields=players%2Cpublishers%2Cgenres%2Coverview%2Clast_updated%2Crating%2Cplatform%2Ccoop%2Cyoutube%2Cos%2Cprocessor%2Cram%2Chdd%2Cvideo%2Csound%2Calternates&include=boxart%2Cplatform&page=2"
    },
    "remaining_monthly_allowance": 2895,
    "extra_allowance": 0,
    "allowance_refresh_timer": 1014265
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear about your question especially on `i just scrolled past become a single image and stick` and I have several questions here:

### Are you trying to append image in this tableview method?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> 

UITableViewCell 
{

}
```

### Why you are trying to save the reference of imageview from the cell

```
self.coverImage = cell.tableViewCoverImage.image!
```

### Where is the piece of code that you are trying to append the images?

Comment: Sorry for not wording it better.  Im not sure how to do a video gif but i did upload a video of it:  https://imgur.com/a/6Mhpjn6  coverImage is only being used to store the image to push it to my detailview controller after you select the cell so i dont have to download again.  Im not using it for anything else.  When I attempted appending the image, i tried to do it in cellForRowAt, yes.

Comment: I updated my original code to show my image array attempt.  Its horrible and wrong, I know, but I cannot wrap my head around how to make it work.

Comment: Problem 1 you are trying to append all the image data to the array
Problem 2 If you are just trying to store these image just to pass the data when click why to save all the image data. just save the image data on tableview didSelect method by accessing the cell through indexPath.row

Comment: cellForRowAt is called multiple times so the same images will be appended to the array so may I ask what is the purpose of saving all these image data? Is it just to pass the data when clicked?

Comment: Its two separate things.  Im downloading the image and then assigning it to the cell and then pushing it to the next view controller when clicked.  It seems to work for that purpose.  The only other place CoverID goes is to the Segue.

As far as the tableview and view controller, i just want to be able to scroll through and have the right images come up.  This works until the pagination call, and then as you can see in the video it falls apart after that.

Comment: You do have arrays of image urls right? And the the codes you trying to fetch image from cell should be done inside completion block
cell. tableViewCoverImage.loadImage(from: self.images[indexPath.row], completed: {
            // do your task here in completion block
        })

Comment: self.network.imageArray.append(cell.tableViewCoverImage.image)

this code must be added inside the completion block and you should check if the imageArray already contains the image data through id or sth

Comment: I ammended the original post with an example of the JSON im getting back.  The urls are in a dictionary which consists of a game id for the key and an array of data which includes the filename for the URL front and back covers for each.

Comment: I did add the code inside the completion block, still crashes.  index out of range.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220539/discussion-between-sudan-suwal-and-thesuffering).